# How to pass by reference in JNI?

Tags: c, reference, java-native-interface, buffer

Ok I know this question has been asked before, but I think the answer is different in this context. So basically I have a C library which contains functions seal and unseal, which look like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JavaTest_securesdk_1seal_1data
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong handle, jbyteArray data, jint size)
{
    const char *cData = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, data NULL);
    jint token = securesdk_seal_data(handle, cData, size);
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, data, cData, JNI_ABORT);
    return token;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JavaTest_securesdk_1unseal_1data
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong handle, jint token, jbyteArray data, jint size)
{
    const char *buffer = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, data NULL);
    jsize length = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env,data);
    jlong address = securesdk_unseal_data(handle, token, buffer, size);
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        printf("%i\n", buffer[i])
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, data, buffer, JNI_ABORT);
    return address;
}
```

Basically the seal function takes in a byte array on the Java side and stores it in flash memory (don't worry how this works) and returns a token. The unseal function takes in an empty byte array buffer and the token and fills the empty buffer with the data. Now here's the java code and what it outputs.

```
class JavaTest{
    public native int securesdk_seal_data(long handle, byte[] data, int size);
    public native int securesdk_unseal_data(long handle, int token, byte[] data, int size);

    JavaTest test = new JavaTest();
    String data = "hello";
    byte[] cmdbuf = data.getBytes();
    int token = test.securesdk_seal_data(sdk, cmdbuf, cmdbuf.length);
    byte[] emptybuf = new byte[10];
    long returnData = test.securesdk_unseal_data(sdk, token, emptybuf, emptybuf.lenth);

    for(int i=0; i<emptybuf.length; i++){
        System.out.print(emptybuf[i]);
    }
}
```

So when I run the java code, it prints out the bytes of "hello" from the printf statement in the C code. When I pass in the empty buffer, it is filled with the data that I sealed originally.This is correct. BUT when I try and print the filled buffer after calling the unseal function in Java, it still returns me the empty buffer. How can I get the buffer to update from memory after calling the C function? Is this possible? I would like it to print out the bytes of "hello" when I print emptybuf from Java and not just from C. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In **unseal**, instead of JNI_ABORT pass 0:

```
(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, data, buffer, 0);
```